$C_{G}(x)\subseteq\bigcap_{\substack{H\le G\\x\in H}}N_{G}(H)$
Let $G$ be a group and $x\in G$. Is the following inclusion true?
$$
C_{G}(x)\subseteq\bigcap_{\substack{H\le G\\x\in H}}N_{G}(H),\;\;x\neq e
$$
$C_{G}(x)=\{g\in G:gx=xg\}$
$N_{G}(H)=\{g\in G:gH=Hg\}$
Approach: If $H=\langle x\rangle$ then $C_{G}(x)\subseteq N_{G}(H)$ but is it true in general?
Any hint would be appreciated.

I would start with $G=\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ and $x=2 \mathrm{Id}$. Then $C_G(x)=G$.  All you need to find now is a subgroup $H$ which contains $x$ and which is not normal. For a general group, pick $x$ to be in the center of $G$ and try to find a subgroup containing $x$ which is not normal.

Pick $G=\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ and $x=2\mathrm{Id}$. Then
$C_G(x)=G.$
Thus, if we can find a non-normal subgroup $H$ of $G$ containing $x$, we are done. Such an example is given by the group of diagonal matrices (Prove that the group of diagonal matrices is not a normal subgroup of the group $\mathrm{GL}_n\,(\mathbb K)$ if $n\ge 2$ and $|K|\ge 3$ for a proof that it is not normal).
